# Using Charindex with in Substring is resulting in error

Tags: sql-server, substring, charindex

I have CHARINDEX function with in SUBSTRING which has to identify delimiter (|) value and return the value as parameter to a substring

When delimiter is present it works fine

```
select SUBSTRING('SH1684|32I5', 1, CHARINDEX('|', 'SH1684|32I5') -1) AS ID
```

where the ID is SH1684

When it is not present

This results in error as

> Msg 536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the substring function.

But my intention is to get value in ID as SH168432I5.

How can I circumvent this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead, by adding the delimiter, you can make sure it is in the correct logical position in cases where it is missing:

```
SELECT LEFT('SH1684|32I5', CHARINDEX('|', 'SH1684|32I5' + '|') - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `CASE` statement to determine if the `|` is present. `CHARINDEX` will return `0` if it's not present:

```
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(15) = 'SH1684|32I5'

-- show the value
SELECT @val

-- returns the section before the pipe
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', @val) > 0
             THEN SUBSTRING('SH1684|32I5', 1,
                            CHARINDEX('|', 'SH1684|32I5') - 1)
             ELSE @val
        END AS ID

-- set value without pipe
SET @val = 'SH168432I5'
-- same query returns entire value as there is no pipe
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|', @val) > 0
             THEN SUBSTRING('SH1684|32I5', 1,
                            CHARINDEX('|', 'SH1684|32I5') - 1)
             ELSE @val
        END AS ID
```

So it will return the portion before the `|` if it's present, otherwise it will return the entire value.

Answer (score 0):

please use select REPLACE('SH1684|32I5', '|', '') . This must work.
[Replace Function Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0rlt.png)